# How do I solve $\gcd(k+8,18)=1$ when $k$ is an integer

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I was trying to find all integers $k$ that verify $\gcd(k+8,18)=1$ and I have no idea where to start.
I tried thinking of Bezout but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Hint:  first show that, if $k$ works, then so does $k+18$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Also, can you solve $\gcd(n,18)=1$?

Comment: $18=2\times3^2$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\gcd(n,18) = 1$ implies that $n$ is not divisible by $2,3$ since $18 = 2\cdot 3^2$. Since any integer can be written as $n = 6p+r, 0\le r \le 5$. Since $n$ is not divisible by either $2$ or $3$, $n = 6p+1$ or $n = 6p+5$. Apply this argument for $n = k+8$, we have: $k+8 =6p+1$ or $k+8 = 6p+5$. So $k = 6p-7$ or $k = 6p-3$. Thus $ k= 6p'+5$ or $k = 6p'+3$. Here $p' = p-2$. In summary: $k = 6m+5$ or $k = 6m+3$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thank you so much ! but may I ask was there a certain reason as to why you chose studying cases in Z/6Z and not for example in Z/9Z ?

Comment: $9k+5$ could be divisible by $2$.

Comment: @OUCHNA **Beware:** the "implies that" should say "if and only if" else to be correct we'd need to explicitly verify that the all the claimed solutions work (i.e. are not extraneous).